# How to make a textview move, rotate and zoom in android

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to add text on image with Zoom, rotate and move properties. I have partially achieved this by converting the text to image, but I want to do the same by using textview only.

Comment: so how does it work with the image?

Comment: I am using something like what is given in this link https://github.com/siddhpuraamitr/Drag-Scale-Rotate-on-Multiple-Images

Comment: Hey @Deepak , have you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This

    public class simpleOnScaleGestureListener extends SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float size = codedText.getTextSize();
            float factor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            int increase = 0;
            if(factor > 1.0f)
                increase = 2;
            else if(factor < 1.0f)
                increase = -2;

            size += increase;


            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //remembering the favourable text size
            Editor edit = sp.edit();
            edit.putFloat("TXTSIZE", size);
            edit.commit();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not getting what is codedText and plainText in this code. can you please give me little brief about that.

Comment: Instead of those just use your text view

Comment: Please share some sample code link, I am not getting this thing.